# java.sql.SQLException: Error preparing query: No tables used

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm using a prepared Statement to insert whit WHERE NOT EXISTS. I have tried different ways, but it simply doesn't work. 
The error I catch with `catch (SQLException sqle)` is

> java.sql.SQLException: Error preparing query: No tables used

My code is:

```
try {
                        //hacer los inserts
                        sql = "INSERT INTO calendario (year, mes, dia, date) "
                                + "SELECT * FROM (SELECT ? as year,? as mes ,? as dia,? as date) AS tmp "
                                + "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM calendario WHERE "
                                + "year=? AND mes=? AND dia=?)";

                        injerto = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                        injerto.setInt(1, year);
                        injerto.setInt(2, mes);
                        injerto.setInt(3, dia);
                        injerto.setDate(4, sqldate);
                        injerto.setInt(5, year);
                        injerto.setInt(6, mes);
                        injerto.setInt(7, dia);
                        injerto.addBatch();
                        injerto.executeBatch();

                    }  catch (SQLException sqle) {
                        sqle.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("Calendario dice: me muero");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
```

I'm using MariaDB, which print this error:

> Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Error preparing query: No tables used

I have tried also with:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO calendario (year, mes, dia, date) "
                                    + "SELECT ?,?,?,?  "
                                    + "WHERE NOT EXISTS ("
                                    + "SELECT * FROM calendario "
                                    + "WHERE year = ? AND mes = ? AND dia = ?)";
```

And the error change:

> Error preparing query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM calendario WHERE year = ? AND mes = ? AND dia = ' at line 1

Help me please.

Comment: There's no from clause in the select.

Comment: You probably want `"INSERT INTO calendario (year, mes, dia, date) "
                                + "VALUES(?,?,?,?) "
                                + "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM calendario WHERE "
                                + "year=? AND mes=? AND dia=?)"`

Comment: You either go full Spanish or full English on your data schema and field names, don't mix them!

Comment: Suggest you read the syntax for `INSERT` https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/insert/  This part of your SQL is weird: `(SELECT ? as year,? as mes ,? as dia,? as date)` You're selecting but not FROM anything.

Comment: The initial query looks syntactically fine (the 2nd one is obviously wrong). Are you sure that you compiled the class with this exact query? Enable general log on the server (`SET GLOBAL general_log=1`), run it again, check the general log to see what query the server is getting, maybe a bug in connector corrupts it somehow. Which versions of the connector and MariaDB server are you using?  @Taylor - there is nothing wrong with running `SELECT 1 AS year, 2 AS mes` without `FROM` clause, as long as everything it selects are constants.

Comment: @elenst yeah but the whole structure of `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ? as year,? as mes ,? as dia,? as date) AS tmp` looks highly suspect to me.

Comment: @Taylor it's uncommon, but not incorrect - as long as all parameters are bound correctly, it will work. And if parameters are missing, there would be a syntax error, not `No tables used`. To get this error, the query which the server receives should be something like `INSERT INTO calendario (year, mes, dia, date) SELECT *`, which makes me think that either the query has been somehow truncated somewhere between the code and the server, or this code is not what is being executed.

Comment: @RC, sorry, didn't work. Maybe it is because is MariaDB.

Comment: @elenst, thank you. It is MariaDB version 10.0.21.

Comment: @Hackerman. It is full spanish, only year and date are in english. Year because "año" could be dangerous and "ano" means another thing.

Comment: Thank you everybody. It was solved with IGNORE. Simple! Isn't it?

Comment: `anio`,`fecha`...malas practicas everywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of both `SELECTs`, turn the `INSERT` into `INSERT IGNORE`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO calendario (year, mes, dia, date)
    VALUES
    ( ?, ?, ?, ? )
```

will insert a new row if it does not already exist.
And add `UNIQUE(year, mes, dia)` so that it knows when to "ignore".